# XCode 11 and Cmake Syntax Highlighting

Tags: xcode, cmake

I am developing CMake scripts to generate XCode in Xcode 11. However, there is no syntax highlighting for `CMakeLists.txt` or `.cmake` files. Is it possible to enable it?

Comment: I have the same question; I've searched high and low and can't find anything at all about it! Very frustrating. I hope someone adds an answer here eventually. Please post an update if you find out through some other method. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Editor -> Syntax coloring -> c++

Comment: Indeed, C++ mode works suprinsingly well for Cmake files!